# Disk sizing considerations for 'tempdb' - Growing substantially two times a year

Tags: sql-server, database-design, tempdb, sql-server-2017

I have an HR software on which an employee of the HR department runs long and complex analyses and calculations about two times in a year. Because of this the `tempdb` is growing to 500GB and even more.

What is a good disk sizing solution? Because the rest of the year `tempdb` is not so big.

**Details**

- The SQL Server version and edition of relevance are 2017 Standard.
- `tempdb` and databases are on the same partition `D:` and Log files are on a different partion `E:`
- The HR database itself has around 78GB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "real" answer is: work with HR and/or their software vendor to fix or improve their twice-annual jobs so they don't do that.

Assuming that's not possible, you're left with <s>two</s> three lousy options:

1. Leave tempdb huge all year long.
2. Leave enough empty space on disk so that tempdb can grow huge, then shrink it back down immediately afterwards.
3. Coordinate with systems to add disk space just before processing, then shrink tempdb afterwards and recover the disk space.

1 and 2 are pretty much functionally identical, although I'd tend toward 2 (just in case the vendor got its act together sometime in the last 6 months and fixed their processing job without you knowing it).

Exactly how to undertake #3 would depend on lots of technical details that will vary by your environment. One method I'd consider would be:

- Before processing, add a large temporary drive (say **z:**) to the server
- Do an `ALTER DATABASE tempdb MODIFY FILE` for each tempdb file, specifying both the new location on **z:** and a larger file size
- Restart SQL for that change to take effect (SQL re-creates tempdb every time it restarts)
- Let tempdb use up as much space as it needs on **z:** during processing
- After processing is done, re-execute the `ALTER DATABASE tempdb MODIFY FILE` to redirect tempdb back to the original drive (and the original smaller size)
- Restart SQL again for the change to take effect
- Drop/remove the now-empty disk

In our environment, this is preferable because (with our particular configuration of SAN/virtualization), it happens to be *vastly* easier to *add and later remove* a drive than it is to *expand an existing drive* and (especially) to *shrink an existing drive*. (If I remember right, shrinking an existing drive literally requires presenting a whole new disk and migrating data). But your mileage may vary depending on your configuration.

Comment: It's a shame `tempdb` does not allow additional filegroups, otherwise this song and dance could be done without restarting SQL Server (by suitably switching to a new default filegroup and emptying the files in the new one later). But, in case anyone else reading this has the same idea: no, you can't do it like that. Doing it with only the default filegroup is theoretically possible, but there's some pitfalls that may mean you have to restart anyway, so you might as well plan for that instead.